# Android Custom Row Layout

Tags: android

I have a problem with a custom RowLayout used for a ListView in Android. It contains an ImageView and a TextView. The Image will appear, however the text will not. Can anyone tell me what i did wrong?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:id="@+id/RowImageView"
    android:src="@drawable/img"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="thisIsATestText"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ImageView` is probably too big so it overlaps your `TextView`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:id="@+id/RowImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="thisIsATestText"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

If you want to use `layout_weight` to define width of your elements, you shouldn't use `wrap_content`. Notice that you used `weightSum="1"` to determine total width of your `LinearLayout`. That's completely fine. That means, that children of this layout should have weight equal to 1 together. As you may have noticed, I used 0.6 for ImageView and 0.4 for TextView. It's also very important to use `layout_width="0dp"` so that the weights work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://.   schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="69dp"
android:id="@+id/RowImageView"
android:src="@drawable/img"
android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:text="thisIsATestText"
android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="69dp"
        android:id="@+id/RowImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        android:text="thisIsATestText"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
    </LinearLayout>
```